# Как правильно использовать хуки в роутинге во Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Всем привет.
Есть кнопка назад, которая полностью повторяет браузерную кнопку go(-1).
Но нужно расширить ее функционал.

Есть роут /betcase, где я создаю дело на него я могу попасть или с главной страницы или с журнала дел /betcasejournal и после успешного создания, мы переходим сразу на роут /betcase/:id. Так вот тут я хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки назад, я попадал или  на главную страницу или в журнал, смотря откуда нажал на роут /betcase. Ceйчас при нажатии кнопки назад меня кидает логично опять на создание дела.

Что-то ковырялся с хуком beforeEach не получилось.
Какой хук тут лучше использовать? Буду благодарен за направление куда думать:)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что мешает просто роутить своей кнопкой на нужную страницу в нужном компоненте.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}" class="btn">Назад</router-link>
```